# How to prove that replacing $f(x)$ with $f(g(x))$ in primitive recursion scheme still yields a primitive recursive function if $g$ is "decreasing"?

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

**Background**

Let all functions under discussion be of the type $(\mathbb{N_0})^n \to \mathbb{N_0}$ where $n\in\mathbb{N_+}$ can vary.

Loosely speaking, an *initial function* is one of three types of functions: the successor function $s(x) = x+1$, constant functions, and projections onto arguments; these latter two can be of any non-zero arity.

> **Definition.** *Primitive recursive functions* (PRF-s) are functions which are either initial functions or are constructed from other PRF-s by applying the scheme of function composition or the scheme of primitive recursion a finite number of times.

For $n=1$, the scheme of primitive recursion is as follows. First, $f(0) := k$ is set to be some constant, $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$. Then for all $x\in\mathbb{N_0}$, we set $f(x + 1) := h(x, f(x))$ where $h$ is already a known PRF. Note that $h$ depends on $f(x)$ specifically. This can be generalised for any $n\in\mathbb{N_+}$ if necessary.

The question is also posed for $n=1$ for simplicity.

**Question** (TL; DR)

What I would like to do is use this slight modification of primitive recursion. The $f(0) := k$ part remains unchanged. Now, for all $x\in\mathbb{N_0}$, let
$$f(x + 1) := h(x, f(g(x))),$$

i.e. instead of $f(x)$, $h$ depends on $f(g(x))$. Additionally assume that $g$ is a PRF and always strictly less then the successor of its input: for all $x\in\mathbb{N_0}$, $g(x) < x + 1$. (This is what is meant by "decreasing" in the title).

- ***Q:*** How to prove that functions obtained by this kind of modified primitive recursion are also PRFs? Can it be done?

**Additional**

It makes some intuitive sense to me that it should be a true statement, but I have been unable to prove this rigorously. You may assume I am familiar with basic properties of PRFs (that one may add fictitious variables, rearragne variables; superposition principle), and that some basic functions (sum, product, non-negative difference and so on) are PRFs. But I am not sure these are of any help here.

Hints are also welcome.

Comment: If something needs clarification, please leave a comment. Would it be a good idea to transfer this question to Stack Overflow if no answer is given here?

Comment: This is not very satisfactory but here is one way that would likely work. As usual, we want to show that: **(1)** The modified recursion scheme can capture all PRFs. **(2)** The modified recursion scheme can only ever produce PRFs. It seems that (1) would be easy to show by just taking $g(x)=x$. For (2), it would be sufficient to show that "do-times programs" can implement the modified recursion scheme.